# Android scheduling or timer APIme

Tags: android, timer, scheduling, alarm

Pardon me if m asking some discussion based questions. I am completely new to android environment and I am developing an android based application wherein i need to apply some modification in messaging system for my project. therein i need to employ a timer facility for the outgoing messages where user could be able to time his message so that at that scheduled time, the sms should go automatically. I want to know which messaging API will help me in implementing so. I can sense that dis is not upto the mark question to be asked but i searched on every site but all work in vain. Hoping to get a positive reply from your side.

Comment: @surirai, you've posted 8 questions total and have never accepted answers to any of your previous questions.  This issue is what Chris is talking about.

Comment: oh. What is the procedure to accept the answers? kindly tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at [ScheduledExecutorService](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

i think this is what you are searching for. This service is able to execute tasks based on TimeUnits in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check out `AlarmManager`.  You can use it to send a custom Intent at some time in the future.  It might be better than other kinds of timers (depending on your situation), because it will cause the phone to wake up when the intent is delivered.  Otherwise, your code might not run if the CPU is asleep.